# Webpage loading

Tags: html, google-pagespeed

When I hit url of my asp .net mvc4 in Chrome browser, it loads slowly but when I hit the same url in other browsers like internet explorer and firefox etc It loads fast. Why? Please any one facing this issue or have resolved this issue.

Comment: Can you provide the url?

Comment: url is test.arcuetechnologies.com

Comment: Your font files are missing http://test.arcuetechnologies.com/ws-ctrl-twist.woff http://test.arcuetechnologies.com/ws-ctrl-twist.ttf . Guess they block the rendering in chrome

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your font files are missing:

```
test.arcuetechnologies.com/ws-ctrl-twist.woff 404
test.arcuetechnologies.com/ws-ctrl-twist.ttf 404
```

They block the rendering in chrome.